# How does becoming undead interact with Constitution score increases?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, ability-scores

In a game that I'm in, the DM has decided to go with a lycan vs. vampire concept, and this has created a few conundrums.

One of the characters in our group is a dragon disciple, and another character is a barbarian. Both of them decided to take the vampire route, but no one is sure what happens with their Constitution-increasing abilities. For example, when the barbarian rages, would that increase his Charisma, instead of his Constitution?

So far as I can find, whenever a creature doesn't have an ability score (such as a construct or an undead or an incorporeal), generally they use another ability score for all purposes the other would cover. For example, undead use their Charisma modifier to determine health and fortitude bonuses, as they don't have a Constitution score.

**When a creature doesn't have an ability score, and that ability score receives an increase from an ability/spell, how does that affect the creature?**

---

*Related question for 3.5e: [Constitution bonus to HP for a necropolitan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45314/23970)*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Constitution bonuses aren't converted to Charisma.

As okeefe points out, undead in Pathfinder use Charisma to determine hit points, saves, and special abilities related to Constitution.  However, that rule does not mention anything about replacing bonuses to Constitution with bonuses to Charisma.  If you have a non-ability in Constitution, then you simply don't gain the effects of that bonus.

Also important to note, from the undead subtype:

> Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms).

And from the Barbarian Rage entry:

> While in rage, a barbarian gains a +4 morale bonus to her Strength and Constitution, as well as a +2 morale bonus on Will saves.

Note that undead are specifically immune to morale effects, and the Barbarian's Rage gives morale bonuses.  In this case, regardless of whether or not the stat boost to Con shifts to Charisma, undead gain no benefits from raging.  You may want to talk to your DM about houseruling some of this stuff if he wants your Barbarian friend to keep being effective.

Comment: It seems you found a RAW answer so +1 for finding it in B&W, however, if I were DM I'd implement rule 0 & fix that up pronto

Comment: Agreed. A good way to look at it: How does being undead affect constitution penalties? The majority of players and DMs would probably agree that undead are immune to CON damage because they lack a CON score. There's nothing to decrease! They should, therefore, behave similarly to buffs; there's nothing there to increase!

Comment: However, in the pathfinder campaign setting books (undead unleashed i believe) we have seen undead barbarians that benefit from rage bonuses, their ability is not exactly the same, but has the same name.

Comment: @ShadowKras Do you have a reference to that, or a link?  I can't find anything like that on the PFSRD, and I'd be happy to add it to my answer if I had a reference.

Comment: It wont show up on PFSRD because it's a campaign setting book. You would have to look for the PDF somewhere or buy it from paizo's website. When i get home i will search my books for the creature's name and will post here.

Comment: But i found another Source on the Monster Codex, the Savage Vampire:
http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vampire%20Savage

Comment: On the Monster Codex though, it gains a special ability called "Undead Barbarian".

Comment: A DM can allow the vampire barbarian to gain an equivalent to the "undead barbarian" unique special ability - perhaps at a cost of (one or several) feats/rage powers

Comment: Also, note that the only (basic) rage feature not dependent on Con is the -2 AC penalty, making the RAW version *very* unattractive...

Answer (score 6):

> *[Bestiary, page 310](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead)*
>
> **Traits**: An undead creature possesses the following traits (unless otherwise noted in a creature's entry).
>
> - No Constitution score. Undead use their Charisma score in place of their Constitution score when calculating hit points, Fortitude saves, and any special ability that relies on Constitution (such as when calculating a breath weapon’s DC).

It seems that everything that would affect Constitution now affects Charisma.

Comment: I really need to double-check that *Pathfinder* hasn't changed something before I answer. Good find. Not sure I like the rule, but in this particular case it's better than 3.5's.

Comment: A bunch of other things when you go undead, like your BAB changes to the 3/4-level progression...

Comment: @okeefe Even if your class has full BAB progression?

Comment: I'm just reporting what it says—check out the link. If someone wants to find rules specifically about undead PCs, that could be very interesting. If being undead was all sunshine and roses, everyone would do it.

Comment: @SimonGill: No, that's the section on the properties of Undead Racial Hit Dice. You don't gain those unless you actually have Undead Racial Hit Dice, and then only for those HD. The things you gain when you become Undead are below, in the Traits section.

Comment: Ah, [vampires](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire) have exceptions to these general undead rules: _The creature's type changes to undead (augmented). Do not recalculate class Hit Dice, BAB, or saves. Change all racial Hit Dice to d8s. Class Hit Dice are unaffected._

Comment: Actually, even though that section says Charisma is used in place of Con, it does NOT say that bonuses to Con transfer to Charisma. I would actually say that bonuses to Con simply do nothing.

Comment: @YogoZuno but now the Barbarian's Rage increases Strength and Charisma (it's a "special ability that relies on Constitution")

Comment: OK, so you use your Charisma to calculate how many rounds a day you can raise your Str and Con. Done.

Comment: Note that undead also have the *Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms).* trait - so most rage effects (*morale* bonuses to Str, Con [Cha with your interpretation?] and will saves) shouldn't have any effect on an undead. The untyped AC penalty is an exception to this, making a bad thing worse...