# Constitution bonus to HP for a necropolitan

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, ability-scores, hit-points, character-levels

In 3.5, players can take the template Necropolitan. This makes them undead, they lose a level, but gain various benefits.

Since undead have no constitution score, what happens to their hit-points during level-up? Does the player simply gain dX + 0?

A related question [for pathfinder was answered here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19421/how-does-becoming-undead-interact-with-constitution-increases), but I am interested in the 3.5 RAW.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [Special Abilities – Nonabilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#nonabilities):

> ### Nonabilities
>
> Some creatures lack certain ability scores. These creatures do not have an ability score of 0 – they lack the ability altogether. **The modifier for a nonability is +0.** Other effects of nonabilities are detailed below.

(**emphasis** mine)

So yes, they add class/type HD +0 each level.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's dX + 0 at level-up.

As an aside, Improved Toughness will still give you +1 per hit die (Sort of like having a Constitution score of 12). Not to mention getting DM's approval for "being created in a desecrated area/by a Dread Necromancer" can also possibly add some bonus hit points per hit die.